# Create a unique sphere geometry from a sphere and a cylinder Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I'm trying to create a bead like object in Three.js, essentially a sphere with a cylinder through it.  I can create the two independently, but I'm wondering how to match the height of the sphere and the cylinder and how to merge / intersect them, so that the result will be one geometry.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //material
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( {
        wireframe: true
    } );

    //sphere
    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2,20,20);
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material );
    scene.add( sphereMesh );


    //cyl
    var cylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 2, 32 );
    var cylinderMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cylinder, material );
    scene.add( cylinderMesh );

    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 5;

    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    render();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RqU2v/

Comment: https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG - http://evanw.github.io/csg.js/

Answer (score 2):

@gaitat, totally awesome, thanks.

here's the solution with ThreeCSG:

```
    //sphere
    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2,20,20);
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material );
    var sphereBSP = new ThreeBSP( sphereMesh );

    //cyl
    var cylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 5, 32 );
    var cylinderMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cylinder, material );
    var cylinderBSP = new ThreeBSP( cylinderMesh );

    //result
    var subtract_bsp = sphereBSP.subtract( cylinderBSP );
    var result = subtract_bsp.toMesh( material );
    result.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    scene.add( result );
```